# jquery toggle row if column value equals

Tags: jquery

I would like to hide some table rows if the column value equals 0.00000000
So far i used this code, but it also hides the rows containing numbers like 10000.00000000
Here are the jquery and html snippets. (The column that needs to match the 0 value is "balance")

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $('#switchbutton').click(function(){
    $('td:contains("0.00000000")').parent().toggle();
}); 

  });
```

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="dash">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col"></th>
      <th scope="col">Ticker</th>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Balance</th>
      <th scope="col">Deposit</th>
      <th scope="col">Withdraw</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

      {% for coin in coins %}

      <tr id="coin-{{ coin.ticker}}">
      <td><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='coins/'+coin.logo) }}" height="32px" width="32px" /></td>
      <td><b>{{ coin.ticker}}</b></td>
      <td>{{  coin.name }}</td>
      <td class="balance">0</td>

      <td><a href="/coins/{{ coin.ticker }}">{% if coin.dep == 0 %}<i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>{% endif %}Deposit</a></td>
      <td><a href="/coins/{{ coin.ticker }}#withdraw">{% if coin.wd == 0 %}<i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>{% endif %}Withdraw</a></td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.each` loop to iterate through your balance td and then compare its values with `0.00000000` if matches toggle its parent .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('#switchbutton').click(function() {
  $(".balance").each(function() {
    //if text equal to..
    if ($(this).text().trim() == "0.00000000") {
      $(this).parent().toggle(); //hide
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover" id="dash">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col"></th>
      <th scope="col">Ticker</th>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Balance</th>
      <th scope="col">Deposit</th>
      <th scope="col">Withdraw</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="coin-{{ coin.ticker}}">
      <td><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='coins/'+coin.logo) }}" height="32px" width="32px" /></td>
      <td><b>0</b></td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td class="balance">0.00000000</td>

      <td><a href="/coins/{{ coin.ticker }}"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>Deposit</a></td>
      <td><a href="/coins/{{ coin.ticker }}#withdraw">Withdraw</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="coin-{{ coin.ticker}}">
      <td><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='coins/'+coin.logo) }}" height="32px" width="32px" /></td>
      <td><b>1</b></td>
      <td>M</td>
      <td class="balance">10000.00000000 </td>

      <td><a href="/coins/{{ coin.ticker }}"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>Deposit</a></td>
      <td><a href="/coins/{{ coin.ticker }}#withdraw">Withdraw</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="coin-{{ coin.ticker}}">
      <td><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='coins/'+coin.logo) }}" height="32px" width="32px" /></td>
      <td><b>2</b></td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td class="balance">0</td>

      <td><a href="/coins/{{ coin.ticker }}"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>Deposit</a></td>
      <td><a href="/coins/{{ coin.ticker }}#withdraw">Withdraw</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="coin-{{ coin.ticker}}">
      <td><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='coins/'+coin.logo) }}" height="32px" width="32px" /></td>
      <td><b>3</b></td>
      <td>D</td>
      <td class="balance">0.000000001</td>

      <td><a href="/coins/{{ coin.ticker }}"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>Deposit</a></td>
      <td><a href="/coins/{{ coin.ticker }}#withdraw">Withdraw</a></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
<button id="switchbutton">SWitch</button>
```